# Drunk squirrel probability riddle

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution

I stumbled upon this question from an old exam, and I was quite curious how to approach it since there are dependent variables at play. It goes like this:

assume that a drunk squirrel is dropped at location i of an 1-dimensional branch of an oak tree,
where i is drawn from a Gaussian $i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_i = 0; \sigma_s² = 4)$. After the drop, the squirrel makes a step to the right
by distance d, where $ d \sim \mathcal{N}(0; 1)$ (If d is negative the squirrel moves to the left). 
If we write f as the final location of the squirrel, we conclude that$ f \sim \mathcal{N}(i; 1)$. d is also independent of i. 
The squirrel ends up at location $f=2$, what is the most likely location $i$ that the squirrel landed on.

My approach was to define the final location as $z = i+d$ which should be normally distributed with the sum of the mean and variances, but then $\mu_z \neq i$ (should be $0$ according to my logic).

Any ideas on how to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9071/intuitive-explanation-of-contribution-to-sum-of-two-normally-distributed-random is related

Hint:

- Write down the likelihood, proportional to the product of the densities of starting at $i$ and then moving by $2-i$
- Find the value of $i$ which maximises this, possibly by taking the derivative of the logarithm of the likelihood, or perhaps by completing the square

This is going to be the same $i$ which minimises $\dfrac{i^2}{4}+\dfrac{(2-i)^2}{1}$

Comment: Thank you! That helped me, so basically, you assume that the probability of moving 2-i and the probability of that starting point are not dependent. Can I ask why? Seems like the final location should depend on the initial

Comment: The likelihoods are in a sense independent but clearly $i$ and $2-i$ are not